# Where to find iText API to download and how and where to install it on my XP O.S to supply a NetBeans 8.0.2 IDE

Tags: pdf, netbeans, itext, windows-xp, txt

I'm trying to use a NetBeans IDE (8.0.2 release) installed on a Windows O.S. (XP. I know, I know, I'm laughable, but it'll do for me, as it has always done so far) to write and try out some very simple code found on the Internet for converting .txt format into .pdf, and I need to add iText API somewhere on the laptop. Here's the list of questions I need an answer to:

- Where do I download the smallest as well as most effective iText package from ? If I go to itextpdf.com site tons of different downloads are possible, and I just get lost: which one is the minimum working package I can and should download in order to make my life the simplest ?
- Where do I install it on my laptop ? That is, in what folder ? The same as where NetBeans is installed or another one ? It's not a whim: in that sea of possible downloads and installation guides everything seems to direct you to a Linux-like environment (that I don't have) with its own way to work.
- If those linux-like downloads are actually Ok for a Windows O.S. laptop, how do I use them ? If I unzip a package onto anywhere, the files deployed have .asc or .jar extensions: is that right ? The fact is I don't recall any other file in the NetBeans folder to have such an extension.

I thank very much in advance everybody who could answer me these questions with the most details you are capable of: don't think or feel you are verbose with me, just overwhelm me with all and any info you have; all of them will contribute to make my NetBeans get all it needs in order to use packages such as com.lowagie.text.* or com.lowagie.text.pdf.*.

UPDATE AFTER AMEDEE ANSWER (CF. OCTOBER, 21, 2020):

Thank you so much for answering me, Amedee. First of all I write down here the complete POM.XML I now have in the Maven project I started:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"             
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>TxtToPdfConverter2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <properties>
        <itext.version>7.1.12</itext.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <!-- add all iText 7 modules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

The snippet I took from the link you provided me is in the tail of this POM.XML file, the rest is what was already in place in the file that was created automaticallty when I created the Maven project.
I post all of this not only because I don't know if I had to tail the snippet to the existing content of the POM file or I just had to overwrite it instead, but also because now I don't know where to write the piece of code to test I found on the Internet (I append it at the end of this comment).
You see, similarly to when I create Java projects in NetBeans where the code is placed in a Java Class file underneath the Java Package (Java Project Name -> Source Packages -> Java Package (called same.Name.Of.The.Java.Project) -> Java Class (usually called the same name as the Java Projet Name)), I saved the code to test in a Java Class file beneath the Maven project (Maven Project Name -> Source Packages -> Java Package (called com.mycompany.sameNameOfTheMavenProject)), but differently from a Java project it seems there's no Compile File feature for it in a Maven Project, and besides, NetBeans sees it as wrong because NetBeans doesn't upload the Lowagie classes and when I try to run it anyway it returns me the message '...  No main classes found ...' .
What am I doing wrong ?
Thank you overwhelmingly much for all the tips, hints, amendements, corrections, integrations that you, Amedee, and all others of you out there will be able to write to me.

```
package com.mycompany.txttopdfconverter2;

import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import com.lowagie.text.*;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.*;

public class TextToPDF{
  public static void main(String arg[]){
    try{
        InputStreamReader in= new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader bin= new BufferedReader(in);
        System.out.println("Enter text:");
          String text=bin.readLine();
          Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 36, 72, 108, 180);
          PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("pdfFile.pdf"));
          document.open();
          document.add(new Paragraph(text));
          System.out.println("Text is inserted into pdf file");
          document.close();
    }catch(Exception e){}
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't mention which version of iText so I will assume the latest version. Go to this page: https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/installation-guidelines/installing-itext-7-for-java and copy the first XML snippet you find. You do not need to download anything. In Netbeans, have a file `pom.xml` in the root of your project (so it must be a Maven project) and paste the copied XML snippet. That's all you need to do, Netbeans should be smart enough to do the rest. If you don't want to use Maven for some reason, then I hope that someone else can help you.

Comment: And if you can't get it to work, show your `pom.xml` file.

Comment: Could you please move all of your code snippets from the comments to the actual question, so that formatting is preserved? My eyes hurt from trying to read it, so I'm not even going to do that. That means, edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64464514/edit

Comment: Done, Amedee. Sorry and thank you

Comment: I hope someone else can help you. I have never used NetBeans, I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Oh and you can (and should) merge the two properties sections.